# FB.api error.. "An access token is required to request this resource"

Tags: javascript, facebook-javascript-sdk

```
FB.api('/1354376857/groups', function(response){
     Data = response.name;
     alert(Data);

     if (response.error) {
        alert(response.error.message);
     }  
});
```

The outputted error message reads: "An access token is required to request this resource" and Data content is undefined for my Facebook app. The user is successfully logged in and the "user_groups" permission has been approved by the user.

I was under the impression that FB.api automatically sets the access token. Any thoughts on why this error is occurring?

Comment: Use access token along with the request http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4758770/how-to-get-access-token-from-fb-login-method-in-javascript-sdk

Comment: Thank you Surabhil.. You're guidance was essential to solving the problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change your code to this

```
var token = "YOUR_TOKEN";
FB.api('/1354376857/groups', function(response){
     Data = response.name;
     alert(Data);
     if (response.error) {
        alert(response.error.message);
     }  
}, {access_token: token});
```

You must pass your access token every time you do a request to the facebook api.

Comment: Thank you- this worked. My steps:                                     1) Generate the token when the user logged in (under FB.login).. Token = response.authResponse.accessToken;                                         2) Store token on server side for easy access                                           3) Use AJAX to access the token when calling Facebook through FB.api calls