# How to get the email's user from facebook apps

Tags: facebook, oauth-2.0, response

I am trying to get information's user from my Facebook app.
I am using the `OAuthUserProvider` to get the response data :

```
array(10) { ["id"]=> string(17) "xxxx" ["first_name"]
=> string(6) "xx" ["gender"]
=> string(4) "male" ["last_name"]
=> string(6) "xx" ["link"]
=> string(62) "https://www.facebook.com/app_scoped_user_id/102xxxx4640725/" ["locale"]
=> string(5) "en_US" ["name"]
=> string(13) "xx xx" ["timezone"]
=> int(1) ["updated_time"]=> string(24) "2014-08-17T21:12:52+0000" ["verified"]
=> bool(true) }
```

It is missing the email and other information. The problem is from my app because when I use other apps it works well. Should I modify my app's setting to get that missed information?

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking. If it is a permission problem, I would start here:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.1
and here
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.1#reference-extended-publish

Comment: Check that you are getting the right access token. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens
See related question (Possible duplicate): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4758770/how-to-get-access-token-from-fb-login-method-in-javascript-sdk

Comment: when i get the response from facebook app, it should give me other fields like email, locale, etc.. in my case they don't figure out !