# Run a method when the on success with facebook login

Tags: facebook-javascript-sdk

I am using the following code for people to log in with facebook on my website.

```
function logintofb (){
 if( navigator.userAgent.match('CriOS') )
window.open('https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?    client_id='+1691221377775124+'&redirect_uri='+ document.location.href +'&scope=publish_actions', '', null);
else
FB.login(function(response) {
// handle the response
}, {scope: 'publish_actions'});

}
```

Now when I have the token I want to run another method, how do I know once the token is received?  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This read might be useful for you:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/4760745/5392479

Alternatively, you can use Fb.Api() and make a graph API call to facebook to get the access token. The graph API path will be available in the developers.facebook.com documentation.

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding my question, I already know how to get the access token, I just want to know how I know when I have it so that I can use it.

Comment: Ahh.. ok.. In that case, Fb js API functions such as login,etc. all these methods trigger REST calls by default and you will get the JSON in the form of response. The very reason you are getting a non-null response means you have got the access token in the response. Hence anything written within the `function(response){ .. }` will be the right place to get the data.

Comment: there are two sections I am asking for the login, the CRiOS and everything else
Where do I ask in the CRiOS section?

Comment: Did you try `var access_token =   FB.getAuthResponse()['accessToken']` to get access token after you perform `window.open`. This might give you the access token after you have completed oauth